# Сфера применения длинной арифметики в Python

Tags: python, арифметика

Как известно в языке Python, числа могут быть сколько угодно большими, в большей степени ограничение накладывает только система на которой работает программист. И у меня возник вопрос, в каких сферах могут применять столь длинные числа, и применяют ли вообще, или же это просто является фишкой данного языка, и по больше части не используется? P.s. У меня в голове только пару мыслей где это могут применять: 1. В научных расчётах. 2. В машинном обучении(возможно).

Comment: Если бы такие числа нигде не применялись, то и библиотек таких бы не было и в языке то же этого не было. И да, это просто фишка языка, что это доступно уже из коробки без дополнительных библиотек.

Comment: Криптография, теория чисел, комбинаторика, вычислительная геометрия (биология), олимпиадное программирование - да. Научные вычисления (скорее инженерные), машинное обучение - нет.

Comment: Это дико удобно когда умножая два целых числа не надо думать о переполнении.

Comment: В сам язык ещё встроены неограниченные рациональные и вещественные произвольной (но конечной) точности. Всё вместе это делает Питон идеальным для прототипирования любых расчётов. И часто прототип так хорош, что его не обогнать и специальным ПО.

Answer (score 3):

> Длинная арифметика применяется в следующих областях:
>
> - составление кода для процессоров (микроконтроллеров) низкой разрядности. Например, микроконтроллеры серии AVR имеют АЦП с разрядностью 10 бит и регистры с разрядностью 8 бит. Этого недостаточно для обработки информации с АЦП; без длинной арифметики не обойтись;
> - криптография. Большинство систем подписывания и шифрования данных используют целочисленную арифметику по модулю m, где m — очень большое натуральное число, не обязательно простое. Например, при реализации метода шифрования RSA, криптосистемы Рабина или схемы Эль-Гамаля требуется обеспечить точность результатов умножения и возведения в степень порядка 10309;
> - математическое (см. список ПО) и финансовое ПО. Результат вычисления на бумаге должен совпадать с результатом работы компьютера с точностью до последнего разряда. В частности, калькулятор Windows (начиная с Windows 95) проводит четыре арифметических действия с намного большей точностью, чем позволяет процессор x86. Для научных и инженерных расчётов длинная арифметика применяется редко, так как ошибки во входных данных обычно намного больше, чем ошибки округления;
> - стандартная тема в спортивном программировании.

https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0